# How to call CallBack(); function again after executing successfully?

Tags: java, android, callback

I have a project that deals with RFID Cards, After tapping the card on the RF Reader, It records the data and needs to run the RFCard Reader again. But my problem is after I tapped the card, The next card that will be tapped is can't read due to the `CallBack();` hasn't run again.

I have tried this, after 3-5 times, the reader has stopped.

```
class  myCallbackThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                //my code of saving will be here...

                myCallbackThread myCallbackThread = new myCallbackThread();
                myCallbackThread.start();

            }catch (Throwable e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

It This full code is a `CallBack();` function. My problem is how can I Call it again to repeat the process after it has successfully executed?

```
 class CallBackThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            RFCardInterface.waitForCardPresent(RFCardInterface.CONTACTLESS_CARD_MODE_AUTO, 1, -1);
            if (RFCardInterface.isCallBackCalled &&
                    RFCardInterface.notifyEvent.eventID == RFCardInterface.CONTACTLESS_CARD_EVENT_FOUND_CARD) {

                IDCatcher = StringUtility.ByteArrayToString(RFCardInterface.notifyEvent.eventData,
                        RFCardInterface.notifyEvent.eventData.length);

                IDCatcher = IDCatcher.substring(9, 21).replace(" ", "");
                Log.e("IDCatcher", IDCatcher);


                EventBus.getDefault().post(new EBTest2());
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve to make it indefinite?. Thank you

**EDIT** Added my `EBtest2()`

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN_ORDERED)
public void onEvent(EBTest2 ebTest2) {

    Cursor c = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select is_arrived,is_closed from trans_settings order by _id desc limit 1", null);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        try {
            String is_arrived = c.getString(0);
            String is_closed = c.getString(1);

            if (is_arrived.equals("0") && is_closed.equals("0")) {
                SearchEmp();
            } else if (is_arrived.equals("1") && is_closed.equals("0")) {
                SearchEmp_isArrived();
            } else if (is_arrived.equals("1") && is_closed.equals("1")) {
                SearchEmp_isClosed();
            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `while` loop to call your **recursive logic** with condition **true**.

Comment: Put it in a while loop

Comment: @BlackFlag  @JeelVankhede . If I will put it on `while()` loop, does it will eat too much memory??

Comment: It shouldn't consume too much as long as garbage collector can clean the unreferenced structures

Comment: @BlackFlag I have added my `EBTest2()` function. every function has a query of it. so that is why I'm curious on the memory side. my POS device is only 1GB RAM only and running on Android 4.4

Comment: Please post your code. Btw, you can watch memory consumption in android studio using adb